Measurement in the eigenbasis of the Hadamard gate
The Hadamard gate $H$ is a unitary and Hermitian matrix, which are as far as I know the requirements to be a valid quantum observable.
The eigenvectors of the Hadamard gate are:
$$
\left|H_+\right\rangle = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) \left|0\right\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) \left|1\right\rangle
$$
and
$$
\left|H_-\right\rangle = \sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{8}\right) \left|0\right\rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) \left|1\right\rangle
$$
named such that $H\left|H_\pm\right\rangle = \pm\left|H_\pm\right\rangle$.
As $\left|H_+\right\rangle = T\left|+\right\rangle$, $\left|H_+\right\rangle$ is central to many magic state distillation protocols.
Measurement in this basis can be emulated with the following circuit:

Since the control Hadamard is a non-Clifford gate, it is not surprising that obtaining $\left|H_+\right\rangle$ is difficult with only Pauli measurements.
In the literature (or at least my exposure to it), $H$ is rarely considered as an observable. Is there any physical or theoretical reason behind this?
I would expect that {Clifford + Pauli measurements + $H$ measurements} is universal, so there is probably something that prevent this gate set to be useful/usable in practice.
May be having access to a native Hadamard measurement makes it difficult to implement Pauli measurements as well, if native Hadamard measurement can even be a thing.

I am not sure if it is possible to center an image.

Repeated measurement in the Hadamard basis is the technique used in "Very low overhead fault-tolerant magic state preparation using redundant ancilla encoding and flag qubits" for improving the fidelity of a magic state.



Note they define the T gate to be $Y^{1/4}$ instead of the usual $Z^{1/4}$. Otherwise Fig2b would be obviously wrong.




Thanks. I was aware of this paper and the older https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07847. My question was more on the physical level, i.e. would it be beneficial to consider $H$ measurement as a primitive of the quantum hardware. Maybe it stands in an awkward spot between the physical level where $H$ might not be particularly important and the logical level where there are ways to emulate it with magic states. The noisy primitive could be a way to get noisy magic states that might be better than with noisy $Z^{1/4}$.

@AG47 I think this kind of thing happens reasonably commonly, but is just described in different terms. For example, applying a T gate by gate teleportation can be thought of in terms of an H basis measurement (or an H basis preparation).
